# Is there a way to strictly search for strings in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table name 'employee' as bellow:

```
 | name      | skills     |
 |------------------------|
 | john      | PHP, HTML  |
 | RIcky     | HTML5, PHP |
 | ROman     | HTML5, HTML|
```

I want to search for `HTML` strictly. I tried:

```
 select * from employee where skills like %HTML%  // show all result. But it should only display row with name 'john' and 'ROman'.

select * from employee where skills like %HTML5%  // show all result. But it should only display row with name 'RIcky' and 'ROman'.
```

How can i do this directly from mysql query.

Updated:
  I couldnot normalize the table because I am working in automatic form builder. Means skills are not static. There may be any values. Like in place of skills user may make other fields with options. Same like survey form biulder.

Comment: you would do the same thing.

Comment: The correct answer would be to normalise your schema.

Comment: Your reasoning for not normalizing the table is invalid. New skill -> new row in skills table, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be proper to use.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'HTML' , REPLACE(skills, SPACE(1), '') ) > 0;
```

Comment: This won't work when there are spaces within strings

Comment: Thank you, this worked but how to make a query for not equals to. Like how to display all result where there is not HTML value.

Comment: Simple, just change the condition from ` FIND_IN_SET( 'HTML' , REPLACE(skills, SPACE(1), '') ) > 0` TO ` FIND_IN_SET( 'HTML' , REPLACE(skills, SPACE(1), '') ) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you've asked for:
You could [normalize your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) table(s) and instead of storing complex datatypes (a list of strings) in one field create three tables:

1) for the properties (skills)
2) for the entities that "have" certain properties (employees having certain skills)
3) a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) where you store the information (a reference) which entity has which properties
This way your relational database system has a much better chance of using indices to find the appropriate data (using LIKE, string functions et al in a WHERE/ON clause usually causes a full table scan and for that you hardly need a database - you can do that with a flat file almost as easily).

E.g. (I didn't pay attention to the indices though)

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

// Which employees have the skill 'HTML' ?
$query = "
    SELECT
        e.name
    FROM
        skills as s
    JOIN
        employee_skills as x
    ON
        s.id=x.id_skill
    JOIN
        employees as e
    ON
        x.id_employee=e.id
    WHERE
        s.name = 'HTML'
";
foreach( $pdo->query($query) as $row ) {
    echo $row['name'], "\r\n";
}

/* creating temporary test tables
   and inserting sample data
*/
function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE employees (
            id int auto_increment,
            name varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE skills (
            id int auto_increment,
            name varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE employee_skills (
            id_employee int,
            id_skill int,
            unique(id_employee,id_skill)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec("
        INSERT INTO employees (id, name) VALUES
        (1, 'John'), (2,'Ricky'), (3,'Roman')
    ");

    $pdo->exec("
        INSERT INTO skills (id, name) VALUES
        (1, 'PHP'), (2,'HTML'), (3,'HTML5')
    "); 

    $pdo->exec("
        INSERT INTO employee_skills (id_employee, id_skill) VALUES
        (1, 1), (1,2),
        (2, 3), (2,1),
        (3, 3), (3,2)
    ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try surrounding the text you are searching for with speechmarks:

```
select * from employee where skills like "%HTML%"
select * from employee where skills like "%HTML5%"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a REGEX-based search

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE skills REGEXP '[[:<:]]HTML[[:>:]]'
```